# Unable to send flutter GET request to python local server

Tags: python, flutter, flask, flutter-web, flask-restful

I've made a simple flutter web app with TextField() and a Text() widget. When I press the button I expect it to send a query to the simple flask app made using python where it will returns the inverted text and I display that on the Text widget.

> NOTE: Inverting text is not the actual task. Its just to check if I'm
> able to get the data.

**Python Code:**

This code works when I run on the chrome.

```
#performing flask imports
from flask import Flask,jsonify
from flask.globals import request


app = Flask(__name__) #intance of our flask application 

#Route '/' to facilitate get request from our flutter app
@app.route("/api",methods=["GET"])
def function():
    d = {}
    text = str(request.args["Query"])
    text = text[::-1]
    d["query"] = text
    return jsonify(d)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**Flutter Code:**

*main.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'api.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String url;

  var data;

  String queryText = "Query";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("PYTHON AND FLUTTER"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: TextField(
                onChanged: (value) {
                  url = "http://10.0.2.2:5000/api?Query=" + value.toString();
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Search Anything Here",
                    suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () async {
                          data = await getData(url);
                          var decodedData = jsonDecode(data);
                          setState(() {
                            queryText = decodedData["Query"];
                          });
                        },
                        child: Icon(Icons.search))),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Text(
                queryText,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*api.dart*

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future getData(url) async {
  http.Response response = await http.get(url);
  return response.body;
}
```

I followed the tutorial from : [This Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXB3gap6P8k&t=75s)

I'm running the python code via Command Prompt and flutter app through VScode.

I'm getting the following errors:

```
Error: Expected a value of type 'Uri', but got one of type 'String'
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:50523/dart_sdk.js:5348:11)
    at Object.castError (http://localhost:50523/dart_sdk.js:5319:15)
    at Object.cast [as as] (http://localhost:50523/dart_sdk.js:5635:17)
    at Function.as_C [as as] (http://localhost:50523/dart_sdk.js:5263:19)
    at getData (http://localhost:50523/packages/word_prediction/api.dart.lib.js:29:47)
    at getData.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:50523/dart_sdk.js:39211:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:50523/dart_sdk.js:39242:7)
    at Object.getData (http://localhost:50523/packages/word_prediction/api.dart.lib.js:28:18)
    at main._MyAppState.new.<anonymous> (http://localhost:50523/packages/word_prediction/main.dart.lib.js:422:48)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:50523/dart_sdk.js:39211:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:50523/dart_sdk.js:39242:7)
    at http://localhost:50523/packages/word_prediction/main.dart.lib.js:421:210
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.invokeCallback (http://localhost:50523/packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart.lib.js:203:18)
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.handleTapUp (http://localhost:50523/packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart.lib.js:417:40)
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.[_checkUp] (http://localhost:50523/packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart.lib.js:223:12)
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.acceptGesture (http://localhost:50523/packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart.lib.js:199:23)
    at arena.GestureArenaManager.new.sweep (http://localhost:50523/packages/flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart.lib.js:222:31)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.handleEvent (http://localhost:50523/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:402:27)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:50523/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:381:24)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:50523/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:6107:13)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.[_handlePointerEventImmediately] (http://localhost:50523/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:352:14)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.handlePointerEvent (http://localhost:50523/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:325:43)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.[_flushPointerEventQueue] (http://localhost:50523/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:314:14)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.[_handlePointerDataPacket] (http://localhost:50523/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:304:65)
    at Object.invoke1 (http://localhost:50523/dart_sdk.js:185426:7)
    at _engine.EnginePlatformDispatcher.__.invokeOnPointerDataPacket (http://localhost:50523/dart_sdk.js:165747:15)
    at _engine.PointerBinding.__.[_onPointerData] (http://localhost:50523/dart_sdk.js:166405:49)
    at http://localhost:50523/dart_sdk.js:166863:28
    at http://localhost:50523/dart_sdk.js:166816:16
    at http://localhost:50523/dart_sdk.js:166509:11
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Future getData(String url) async {
  var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  return response.body;
}
```

Comment: I didn't get the above error, but code didn't work either. I pressed button 2-3 times but nothing happend and suddenly execution stopped in browser_client.dart flie at line no 69 (completer.completeError).

Comment: Have you tried to run your API request in your terminal? In Linux you can use: `curl -X GET "http://10.0.2.2:5000/api?Query=my_value"` this way you can check if your server is working OK

Comment: It's strange, because your error says clearly the error is about missing **Uri**. Make a simple script in Dart only requesting a particular **url**, check if error persists.

Comment: The solution you provided is correct. But along with that, some changes were required on server side code to fully make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Along this change https://stackoverflow.com/a/66517561/13592012 mentioned by Ουιλιαμ Αρκευα.

There was another problem:
*When I use Break point it shows file call by blinding.dart*

This was because of CORS.

**Cross Origin Request(CORS)** error which was because I did not set this up in my server.

This is especially if your flutter web application is not running in the same domain as the server where you api is running. Even if its on the same machine, you will have to allow the request from certain domain and ports.

This can be done by adding the following lines to flask code:

```
response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

and

```
response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
```

So the updated code will be:

```
#performing flask imports
from flask import Flask,jsonify
from flask.globals import request


app = Flask(__name__) #intance of our flask application 

#Route '/' to facilitate get request from our flutter app
@app.route("/api",methods=["GET"])
def word_predictor():
    d = {}
    text = str(request.args["Query"])
    text = text[::-1]
    d["Query"] = text
    response = jsonify(d)
    response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And, with these two changes, code works fine.